# jetty настройка lo4j

Tags: java, log4j

Как я понял jetty использует log4j. Я создал проект типа maven и при сборке в исполняемый jar соответственно программа запускается без консоли.
В случаи command line app проекта весь лог можно увидеть в этой самой консоли.

1)Где мне посмотреть этот самый лог в случаи maven проекта?
2)Каким образом мне настроить что бы лог ввелся в нужный для меня файл?
3)Как из maven проекта в случаи необходимости вызвать консоль?

Answer (score 1):

1. Maven - это просто сборщик. Способ сборки и запуска не должен влиять на поведение программы, если она нормально написана. За исключение специально предусмотренных случаев, вроде запуска в тестовом окружении.
2. Указать его в соответствующем [аппендере](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender).
3. Вызвать maven-проект из консоли.